# Chef shell_out just giving hex values

Tags: ruby, hex, chef-infra, chef-recipe, ohai-gem

I'm creating the Chef recipe below. However, my shell_out calls are just returning hex values for the expanded variable. How to get the value of the find command in the variable, and not a junk hex value?

Here is the relevant code snipet from my recipe::

```
so = nil

bash "getPath" do
  Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
  command = "find \/ -path \\*ohai\/plugins"
  so = shell_out(command)
end

listOfFiles = ["#{so}\cert.rb","#{so}\key.rb","#{so}\perms.rb","#{so}\propertiesFiles.rb","#{so}\warFiles.rb","#{so}\yum.rb"]
templates = { 1 => "cert.rb", 2 => "key.rb", 3 => "perms.rb", 4 => "propertiesFiles.rb", 5 => "warFiles.rb", 6 => "yum.rb" }
i = 1

listOfFiles.each do |remote|
  template "#{remote}" do
    source 'cert.rb' #this is going to be a variable once I figure out how to call it from the "templates" hash. Just doing a static file for troubleshooting purposes now
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
  action :create
  end
end
```

Here is part of the chef-client run output:

```
- create new file #<Mixlib::ShellOut:0x00000004dd88b8>yum.rb
- update content in file #<Mixlib::ShellOut:0x00000004dd88b8>yum.rb from none to fccd51
--- #<Mixlib::ShellOut:0x00000004dd88b8>yum.rb      2016-10-31 11:52:40.652276263 -0400
+++ ./.chef-#<Mixlib::ShellOut:0x00000004dd88b8>yum20161031-8408-1svdruo.rb 2016-10-31 11:52:40.652276263 -0400
@@ -1 +1,17 @@
+#
+# Cookbook Name:: inventory
+# Recipe:: default
+#
+# Copyright (c) 2016 me, All Rights Reserved.
+
+Ohai.plugin(:Cert) do
+  provides 'certFiles'
+
+  collect_data(:linux) do
+    certFiles Mash.new
+    so = shell_out("find \/ -name \"*.crt\"")
+    certFiles[:values] = so.stdout
+  end
+end
+
- change mode from '' to '0644'
- change owner from '' to 'root'
- change group from '' to 'root'
- restore selinux security context
  * ohai[reload] action reloadPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY
- re-run ohai and merge results into node attributes

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 8/20 resources updated in 05 seconds
[root@host plugins]# PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY^C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there!

```
so = shell_out(command) # Returns a Mixlib::ShellOut object
output = so.stdout      # Returns stdout of your command, as String
```